# Natural Deduction proof of $((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \land B) \rightarrow A$

Tags: logic

I am struggling to find a Natural Deduction proof for

$$((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \land B) \rightarrow A$$

I have tried out quite a few things now, but I can not find a way. Could you help me?

Comment: The parentheses are not balanced.

Comment: @martycohen: Sorry, I corrected the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to prove a conditional statement in natural deduction is to assume the antecedent and prove the consequent.  So I would start by assuming $(A \to B) \to A \wedge B$, and try to prove $A$.  Since there is no obvious way to reason directly from the assumption to $A$, the next thing I would try is to assume $\neg A$ and try to reach a contradiction.  That gives you a start; see if you can continue on from there.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do it by parts.

\begin{align*}
(A\to B)\to(A\wedge B) & \Longleftrightarrow (\neg A\vee B)\to(A\wedge B)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg(\neg A\vee B)\vee(A\wedge B)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (A\wedge\neg B)\vee(A\wedge B)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow A\wedge(\neg B\vee B)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow A\wedge T\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow A
\end{align*}

where $T$ represents a tautology.

Consequently, the proposed formula is equivalent to $A\to A$, which is a tautology itself.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The question is asking for a "natural proof" for it.  In other words, how might you think this through in your daily life?  Although your proof is correct, I don't think it qualifies as a "natural proof".

Comment: No, the question asked for a "natural deduction" proof.  Natural deduction is a particular style of formal deduction; it does not mean "thinking things through in your daily life."